# How to retrieve audit logs for user sign ins in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-identity

I am in need to get Audit logs for events related to user sign ins to Google cloud platform. I have searched the documentation and even after enabling all audit data sources in the IAM I can't seen any logs related to user authentication in the Logging Explorer.

Does anybody know which steps I am missing?

Comment: AFAIK you can't log when a user log in but only their actions in GCP.

Comment: Thank you @Puteri, do you know if there is a proxy way of retrieving that information? For example any user action that would resemble an access to the console?

Comment: You have logs when a user reach a service on the console. But the user which use the API is logged only when those API are called. If you have Google Workspace subscription, you can see the login activity in it about the Google account activity, but it's not related to Google Cloud specifically.

Comment: Users do not log into Google Cloud. Authentication is handled by a different Google service. You cannot access login information except if the user is part of your Google Workspace and I think that is limited to the last login.

Answer (score 0):

There are different [types of audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit#services) that you can view for GCP. Most of them are triggered only once you do an API call (use the service). If you want the full list of services that writes a log, you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/services#gcp-audit-logs).

If you want to expand visibility with your resources you may use the following services:

- For admin access logs and approval control: [Access Transparency and Access Approval](https://cloud.google.com/access-transparency?hl=en)
- For SIEM purposes: [Security Command Center](https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks! What I need are the Google Workspace logs for user access within the organization.