How to get all users logged into GCP project
I am trying to build a dashboard to get all logged in users accessing GCP project. Is there a way to get the details from the log explorer and build a dashboard for monitoring and alerting. I am not the admin of the google account, so don't have access to admin console. Wanted to build dashboard on Google cloud console
I tried to put filter in Audit logs, but its pulling all activities for all users using the specific gcp project

You can't have user logged list. You can have the user activity when they access, or change value on different services. Can you detail your target and expectation?

Requirement is to have a monitoring and alerting system for all user logins. Wanted to see in a dashboard how many user login/access particular GCP project. Not all the activities. Wanted to see a unique entry for each user accessing GCP project

You can't get that info. Firstly, you don't login to GCP, you log in to your Google account which is used to authenticate you into GCP. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77586390/how-to-retrieve-audit-logs-for-user-sign-ins-in-google-cloud#comment136780574_77586390

You can create a Log sink and include in your filter:

"cloudaudit.googleapis.com/activity"
"cloudaudit.googleapis.com/data_access"
"cloudaudit.googleapis.com/system_event"
"cloudaudit.googleapis.com/access_transparency"


I wanted to see only user email/service account who access the GCP project, not all the activities they performed
